# React Native and Onesignal

Tags: reactjs, react-native, onesignal, react-native-onesignal

`Could not load RNOneSignal native module. Make sure native dependencies are properly linked.`

I want to send notifications in a WebView application with OneSignal, but I keep getting this error, how can I solve it?

I checked the dependencies and rebuilt the application.

Comment: check this issue https://github.com/OneSignal/react-native-onesignal/issues/1345

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.